# Registro de comprobantes de pago en una base de datos (factura, nota de crédito, boleta, nota de débito)

Tags: c#, sql, mysqli

Cómo debería manejar registro de los comprobantes en una base de datos (factura, nota de crédito, boleta, nota de débito etc) en una sola tabla o diferentes ? porque los campos de cada comprobante no varia mucho y creo que debería manejar en una sola tabla. gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Esto dependera de ti en mi opinion deberias separar una tabla para factura, otra para nota de credito y asi...al momento de buscar un documento si solo tienes 100 registro no tardara nada , pero si tienes 1000000 y deseas buscar una nota de credito tardara mas por que tienes diferentes tipos de documentos alli, seria mas optimo separar para cada tipo, dato que a futuro podrian pedirte cambios para algun campo adicional en uno u otro documento y es mas factible si lo tienes separado

Comment: Otra opción que puedes hacer una tabla padre con los datos comunes y creas las tablas hijas : factura, nota de crédito, boleta etc

Comment: Todo depende del caso de uso. No se puede dar una respuesta en el aire a esto.No hay una sola forma.

Comment: @Tegito123 si tenes problemas para buscar en 10M de registros, consideraria decirte que tenes que revisar tus indices ;)

Comment: En los sistemas ERP como lo manejan alguien sabe ?